# How to use TextJOIN with Live Google Form Data

Tags: arrays, google-sheets, google-forms, textjoin

I'm trying to use a TEXTJOIN formula along with an ArrayFormula.  I'm using this on Gform data.  All I need is for my formula to be automatic, and be in a specific format to reference another tab that I am using a VLOOKUP formula for.  The formula that I'm using is =ARRAYFORMULA(TEXTJOIN(", ",TRUE,J2,L2,H2,I2,K2,M2,O2)).  I just need this formula to occur everytime a new form submission comes in.

From what I'm reading, I don't think that you can use text join with array.  However, I don't know how to make my text join formula work with incoming live data from a google form.  I need a specific combination as a result of the textjoin formula.  And I need it to be automatic.

Answer (score 0):

You may try:

```
={"TextJOIN Formula";
   byrow(choosecols(indirect("A2:O"),10,12,8,9,11,13,15),lambda(Σ,if(counta(Σ)=0,,textjoin(", ",1,Σ))))}
```

[image]

Comment: Omg this was a life saver!  Thank you so much!